# Jquery loop coding

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I have problem with my jQuery loop. It not stopped after reach the 10th element, just display 10 times every element. I don't know where is the problem. I must add the counter (z) after the if clause, because I want to display 10 elements of the filtered items (I do this easily if I must not filter the elements).

The part of the code:

```
 function(data) {

      $.each(data.query.results.tbody, function (i, e) {

..
...
....
......

    if (x != '-') {
        var z;
        for (z = 0; z < 10;) {
            $(".news").append('xxxxx');
            z++
        }
    }

            });
  }

);
```

Comment: "It displays every news 10 times", is this mean that you have 10 items and they are all displayed 10 times so 10x10 = total 100 items are displayed?

Comment: It displaying 10 times every filtered news. So 10 times xnews, 10 times ynews, 10 times znews

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp='';
for (z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    temp += "xxxx";
}
$(".news").append(temp);
```

Append the var outside the loop.
Creare a var temp, append data to it and after your loop completes, post that do the append:
https://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is temp += "xxxx"; ?  And could I use this after the if clause? Because I must use the if clause.

Comment: I tried your code, nothing happened. It display every filtered items one time, just not 10 items.